# Vue JS pass data via link to component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

within a component I have a select input. Depending on what was selected, an upload input displays.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" id="uploadType" v-model="uploadType">
        <option value="">Please select...</option>
        <option value="1">Image</option>
        <option value="2">PDF</option>
        <option value="3">Text</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-if="uploadType == '1'">
    <uploader :options="options" ref="uploader" file-success="fileSuccess" @file-error="fileError">
        <uploader-drop>
            <uploader-btn :attrs="attrs1" :single=true>select files</uploader-btn>
        </uploader-drop>
    </uploader>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-if="uploadType == '2'">
    <uploader :options="options" ref="uploader" @file-success="fileSuccess" @file-error="fileError">
        <uploader-drop>
            <uploader-btn :attrs="attrs2" :multiple=true>select files</uploader-btn>
        </uploader-drop>
    </uploader>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-if="uploadType == '3'">
    <uploader :options="options" ref="uploader" @file-success="fileSuccess" @file-error="fileError">
        <uploader-drop>
            <uploader-btn :attrs="attrs3" :single=true>select files</uploader-btn>
        </uploader-drop>
    </uploader>
</div>

<script>
    import uploader from 'vue-simple-uploader'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                uploadType: '',
                options: {
                    target: 'upload'
                },
                attrs1: {
                    accept: '.jpg'
                },
                attrs2: {
                    accept: '.pdf'
                },
                attrs3: {
                    accept: '.txt'
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fileSuccess (rootFile, file, message) {
                console.log(message)
            },
            fileError (rootFile, file, message) {
                console.log(message)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now obviously that is messy, I am repeating code which isn't great.  Also, the select is no longer really needed.  Instead, within another page, I have a links like so

```
<router-link to="/uploadFile" tag="a" class="btn navbar-btn" exact>
    Upload Image
</router-link>

<router-link to="/uploadFile" tag="a" class="btn navbar-btn" exact>
    Upload PDF
</router-link>

<router-link to="/uploadFile" tag="a" class="btn navbar-btn" exact>
    Upload Text
</router-link>
```

What I wanted to try is send the type (image, pdf or text) via the clicked link.  Within the upload component, I could then somehow set this dynamically to the uploadType.  I would 
also need to make the second upload allow multiples, as well a change the accepted types.

Is there any way I can do this through the links?  Quite hard to explain, but I am basically trying to make my upload component reusable.  I almost need something like props, but for a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$route.params` ,for more info check out the [Vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object)

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```